# Add text above barcode and change fontsize using Barbecue

Tags: java, barcode, barbecue

I'm using barbecue to generate barcodes in java. It generates barcodes successfully but there is a small issue. I would like to add some little text just above the barcode. I would also like to change the font size/style of the text/numbers below the barcode and remove the underline as well. How do you go about that?

Here's my code:

```
private void btnGenerateBarcodeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String text=txtText.getText();
    File file = new File("path/to/destination/file");
    try {

        Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(text);
        barcode.setBarHeight(50);
        barcode.setBarWidth(1);
        BarcodeImageHandler.saveJPEG(barcode,file);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Barcode generated successfully!",
            "Success",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error generating barcode\n"+e.toString(),
                "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

[image: barcode]